# The number of positive integers $ n=2^a3^b$ such that $n^6$ does not divide $6^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

$6^n=(2\cdot3)^n$ is not divisible by $n^6$
So we have to find those numbers which does not divide 6 and also expressed by the prime factors of 2 and 3 but after this I am getting no way to proceed .

Comment: What is your question in the end? Find all positive $n$ such that $n^6$ does not divide $6^n$? Because the number of such are infinitely many : any $n \neq 1$ coprime to $6$ will work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $n = 2^a 3^b$, $n^6 = 2^{6a} 3^{6b}$.  What must be true for this not to divide $2^n 3^n$?

Comment: Is it like 6a and 6b will not divide (2^a)×(3^b)?